# Exlude a page from htaccess Rewrite rule

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I've a WordPress install where I have redirected all pages (except the wp-admin and wp-login) to a different url.

I want to exclude one page (called /your-login) from being redirected. This page is in effect the wp-admin page where the login slug has been changed.

How can I exclude this page from being redirected in the htaccess file?

The current code I'm using to perform the redirects in the htaccess file is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/wp-admin|.*wp-login\.php.*) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://mywebsite.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

where mywebsite.co.uk would be the site being redirected to.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/wp-admin|.*wp-login\.php.*) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/your-login/$
RewriteRule (.*) https://mywebsite.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Another solution is a plugin

https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/